# Web Api returns expanded key-value object instead of original JSON object

Tags: c#, mongodb, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

When I send `{"name":"John Doe", "age":18, "country":"USA"}` to my C# Web API with `POST` to `api/test`, I store it in my mongo `test`-collection and return the updated document:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{collection}")]
public IHttpActionResult Upsert(string collection, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var document = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var doc = BsonDocument.Parse(document);
    var result = new Db(collection).Upsert(doc).Result;
    return Ok(result);
}
```

.

```
public async Task<BsonDocument> Upsert(BsonDocument document)
{
    if (document.Contains("_id"))
    {
        await _collection.ReplaceOneAsync(w => w["_id"] == document["_id"], document);
    }
    else
    {
        await _collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
    }
    return document;
}
```

This works, but the result is now a key-value object:

```
[
  {
    "_name": "_id",
    "_value": "56e9364d942e1f287805e170"
  },
  {
    "_name": "name",
    "_value": "John Doe"
  },
  {
    "_name": "age",
    "_value": 18
  },
  {
    "_name": "country",
    "_value": "USA"
  }
]
```

What I would expect is:

```
{
    "_id": "56e9364d942e1f287805e170", 
    "name":"John Doe", 
    "age":18, 
    "country":"USA"
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning directly a `BsonDocument` which WebAPI is serializing to JSON as best as it can, but not correctly.

Try calling `MongoDB.Bson.BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson` which will serialize it correctly to JSON ?

And to return the raw JSON:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(document.ToJson(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") };
```

Comment: I don't think this is a real solution, as you need to do it every single time you need to return a bson document, this is a quick way just to make it work but not a maintainable one

Comment: @LouieAlmeda It answers my question perfectly though, if you care about maintainability, wrap it in a custom method/class like I did.

Comment: @Sven would you mind sharing your solution for it? thanks :)

Comment: The code is proof of concept, it's up to you to decide how you integrate it in a maintainable way. Easiest is to create a function: https://gist.github.com/chris03/c34d865a5ae9db81e00a8ece368782c4

Answer (score 3):

There is an extension method "ToJson" in MongoDB.Bson that returns the json you prefer.

You could add Converter in your serialization settings which will use this method:

```
public class BsonDocumentJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(BsonDocument);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string json = (value as BsonDocument).ToJson();
        writer.WriteRawValue(json);
    }
}
```

Add the converter in your WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;

        settings.Converters.Add(new BsonDocumentJsonConverter());
    }
}
```